# Direct download link for ColdFusion 9 Installer (64-bit Windows)

Tags: coldfusion-9

The Adobe downloads area is down right now - does anyone have a direct download link for the 64-bit Windows installer of ColdFusion 9? I have looked through the Adobe FTP site (ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe) and can't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For now you can get Adobe CF 9.02 for 64-bit Windows (the full installer, there is no 9.02 update) at http://download.macromedia.com/pub/coldfusion/cf9_installer/ColdFusion_9_WWEJ_win64.exe which will be approximately 405MB vs. the other full ACF9 installers: 433MB for 9.0 and 454MB for 9.01 (which is no longer available).

For other versions\operating-systems I recommend trying archive.org (https://web.archive.org/web/20120702030058/http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads_updates.html) to hopefully get the version that you need.

Also to correct Mike Causer's post, that link (http://trials.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/CSTD/9/win64/ColdFusion_9_WWE_win64.exe), as of today, is only 9.0 and not 9.01. So if you are looking for 9.01 you will have to get 9.0 first and then 9.01 as an update (http://download.macromedia.com/pub/coldfusion/updates/901/ColdFusion_update_901_WWEJ_win64.exe).

I believe this is all due to the fact that upon the release of 9.02 they republished 9.0 (without Verity search) and essentially got rid of the 9.01 full installer, leaving 9.01 only available as an update. You can read more about part of this situation in a good post of Charlie Arehart's that covers the release of ACF 9.02 at http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/8/19/understanding_ColdFusion_9.0.2_a_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

To update answer We have [CF repository](http://www.cfmlrepo.com/)

> Where old ColdFusion/CFML Downloads & Installers go to live on for
>   eternity

Here is the direct download link for 
[Coldfusion 9 windows installer 64 bit](https://e05ac1a30afa93e642cc134035af0ab2babf7ac5.googledrive.com/host/0B-P1-Q_5RyjoMHZ2ZEtieXZjZG8/AdobeColdFusion/9.0.0/ColdFusion_9_WWE_win64.exe)

Answer (score 0):

The direct link for download coldfusion 9 x64 is:
http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads_updates.html#cf9