# ColdFusion9 How do I format columns in excel from within a <cfscript>

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using CF9. I've created a multi-sheet workbook. I am attempting to format the columns for each sheet. The formatting is only taking on the first sheet. How can I get it to apply to all sheets? Also I cannot figure out how to get the column width to work for any sheet.

Here's the code that I've got at the moment:

```
    <cfscript>
    qExecSummary = queryNew("");
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "responsible", [1,12,13]);
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "bud_sum", [100,500,1000]);
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "Spent_YTD", [10,50,100]);
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "Name", ["A","B","C"]);
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "Description", ["Descrip1","Descrip2","Descrip3"]);
    queryAddColumn(qExecSummary, "Committed", ["Committed1","Committed2","Committed3"]);


    //Create new workbook with one sheet
    //by default that sheet is the active sheet
    Workbook = SpreadsheetNew("ExecSummary");
    //Add Data to the sheet
    //Formatting
    format1.bold="true";
    format1.fontsize=12;
    format1.font="Calibri";
    format2.bold="true";
    format2.fontsize=18;
    format2.font="Calibri";
    formatNum.dataformat="0.0%";
    //adding the formating to the cells
    //adding the Headers
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Executive Summary Report",1,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format2,1,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"#dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')#",3,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,3,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Data Date",5,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,1);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,1,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Level",5,2);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,2);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,2,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Name",5,3);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,3);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,3,17);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Description",5,4);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,4);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,4,20);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Budget",5,5);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,5);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,5,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Commited",5,6);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,6);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,6,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Spent YTD",5,7);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,7);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,7,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"% Spent",5,8);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,8);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,8,15);
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 6;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-5],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-5],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-5],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-5],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 6 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }

    SpreadsheetCreateSheet(Workbook,"ExecSummary331-333");
    SpreadsheetSetActiveSheet(Workbook,"ExecSummary331-333");

    //adding the Headers
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Executive Summary Report",1,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,{bold="true"},1,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,{fontsize=18},1,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,{font="Calibri"},1,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"#dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')#",3,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,3,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Data Date",5,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,1);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,1,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Level",5,2);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,2);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,2,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Name",5,3);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,3);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,3,17);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Description",5,4);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,4);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,4,20);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Budget",5,5);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,5);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,5,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Commited",5,6);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,6);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,6,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Spent YTD",5,7);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,7);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,7,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"% Spent",5,8);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,8);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,8,15);
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 6;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-5],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-5],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-5],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-5],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 6 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 18;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-17],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-17],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-17],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-17],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-17],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-17]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 17 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 29;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-28],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-28],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-28],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-28],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-28],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-28]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 28 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }

    SpreadsheetCreateSheet(Workbook,"ExecSummary334-336");
    SpreadsheetSetActiveSheet(Workbook,"ExecSummary334-336");

    //adding the Headers
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Executive Summary Report",1,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format2,1,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"#dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')#",3,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,3,1);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Data Date",5,1);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,1);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,1,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Level",5,2);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,2);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,2,10);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Name",5,3);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,3);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,3,17);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Description",5,4);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,4);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,4,20);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Budget",5,5);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,5);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,5,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Commited",5,6);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,6);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,6,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"Spent YTD",5,7);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,7);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,7,15);
    SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,"% Spent",5,8);
    Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,format1,5,8);
    SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Workbook,8,15);
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 6;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-5],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-5],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-5],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-5],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-5]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-5]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 6 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 18;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-17],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-17],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-17],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-17],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-17],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-17]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-17]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 17 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }
    //check to make sure that data was pulled back by the query
    if (qExecSummary.recordCount) {
        rowNum = 29;
        do {//if data is pulled back loop through it and add it to the correct cell
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,dateFormat(now(),'mm/dd/yyy'),rowNum,1);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.responsible[rowNum-28],rowNum,2);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.name[rowNum-28],rowNum,3);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Description[rowNum-28],rowNum,4);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28],rowNum,5);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.committed[rowNum-28],rowNum,6);
            SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-28],rowNum,7);
            if (qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28] NEQ 0){
                Spreadsheetformatcell(Workbook,formatNum,rowNum,8);//if there is a percentage used then format as a percent
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,(qExecSummary.Spent_YTD[rowNum-28]/qExecSummary.bud_sum[rowNum-28]),rowNum,8);
            }
            else {
                SpreadSheetSetCellValue(Workbook,0,rowNum,8);
            }
            rowNum++;
        } while (rowNum - 28 LT qExecSummary.recordCount);
    } else {
        SpreadSheetAddRows(Workbook,"No results for your criteria.");
    }

    SpreadsheetSetActiveSheet(Workbook,"ExecSummary");
</cfscript>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='attachment; filename="execSummaryNew.xls"'>
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#SpreadsheetReadBinary(Workbook)#" reset="true">
```

I know that it's really long, but that's how I had to do it because of the DB that I have to work with, I had to use several queries to get the data how I wanted it.

I have tried having the `SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth` inside the `<cfscript>` to format the columns, but that didn't work either. Right now the formatting only works on the first sheet except for the width which doesn't work on any sheet.

**EDIT**

I almost have it all working. Now it's just the formatting. It works for 2.5 sheets. On the 3rd sheet it stops working half way through. There are 8 columns and the last 4 are not taking the formatting. I've tried everything that I can think of to get it to take. I've added it as an example [here](http://trycf.com/gist/b46ee84e5527653b7e8f69e422228f00/acf2016?theme=monokai), I know that it's long, but I cannot reproduce the problem anywhere. I only get it in production. I've copied what I've got in prod both to my computer and to that example I linked above. Both on my local computer and in the example it works fine. But I have CF 2016 and the prod server is CF 9.

I know it's a lot of code to look at, but if someone could help that'd be great. I'm banging my head against the wall trying to see where I messed it up, but for each sheet I copied the sheet before it and then changed the query numbers, so it should be working.

I can update the example posted here as well, but like I said the example that I'm using is long.

**FINAL EDIT**

[Here](http://trycf.com/gist/bc476779c0132f3c4ffb2a054fc65fd2/acf2016?theme=monokai) is the completed code as an example. It generates 3 sheets and the second two sheets run the query 3 times to fill out the page. each sheet has the same headings and formatting.

Comment: I would try setting the width on something smaller and simplier. I would then add the data in later. I suspect that either something in there is triggering the width not being set OR it as never set in the first place. Either way, this is way too much code to sift through. Create a smaller example of your issue.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I removed about 200 lines of code to make it simpler. Still doesn't format the second sheet or take the width that I'm trying to specify. Other than setting the width at the bottom, I don't set it anywhere else.

Comment: "Didn't work" how? SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth only operates on the *active* sheet. So invoking it once, at the very end, is not going to work. It must be invoked on *each* sheet, for each column you wish to modify. **(Edit)** Is the real report going to output the same query columns on each sheet or is that just for demo purposes? It the query columns really will be the same, the code could be simplified a LOT.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. That's my best advice. I've had too many "won't fix" bugs with CFSpreadsheet in CF9-10 that you will continue to encounter anomalies regardless of how correct your code is... multiple spreadsheets only magnify the problems. You will have better formatting & width support using POIUtility. https://github.com/bennadel/POIUtility.cfc

Comment: @Leigh The formatting, added to each sheet, does not change the column width. The rest of the formatting only applies to the first sheet.  **EDIT**  Yes all three sheets will have the same headers only the data will be different for each.

Comment: @JamesMoberg I would love to be able to use that POIUtitlity, but I don't have access to the server, only the files. I am not able to add anything to the server. I'm just updating the code so it continues to work till it gets decommissioned and the data is migrated to a different system all together.

Comment: @Mike - Are you saying you invoked SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth (not format cell) and it did not change the width? BTW, while we appreciate the desire to provide all of the necessary information, it is way more code than most of us have time to review :) You can reproduce the issue with a lot less code (and increase your chances of getting a fast answer as well). A single, hard coded, SpreadSheetSetCellValue for each sheet should do it.

Comment: @Mike- Just to clarify, "formatting" will not affect column width - only SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth will. If you are not doing that, for each sheet, that would explain the results you are seeing. Run this simpler example http://trycf.com/gist/1ae77c40d17e5f287db325472e82e6e2/acf?theme=monokai . If it works in your environment, the most likely cause is your code. That said, I agree with James that the spreadsheet functions were very buggy in earlier versions. So while less likely, a bug is also possible. Running the simplified example should tell us which one.

Comment: @Leigh I tried your example. Moved the `SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth` to be after the cell values were set. It is still not changing the width of the column to be what I want. I notice in your example that the column widths you use are whole numbers. I'm trying to use decimals, does that matter? I'll test and see, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: @Leigh I added another sheet to my workbook to test your example code.  I almost works. I copied it out and used what you had under `sheet3` to make my new sheet. It added width to the columns, but did not fully expand them. column 1 should be 20, but is 19.29 and column 2 shoild be 50, but is 49.29. Is this a built in limitation where it is taking into account something that I'm not setting that is part of the cell like padding or edges?

Comment: Okay, then it is actually working.  I do not have time to dig up an example, but if you do a search on Excel and how it calculates column widths and you will discover it is measurement methods are incredibly convoluted IMO, and not as simple as you would think... Bottom line, you will have to read up on it and play around with the settings.

Comment: @Leigh So I found that the `SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth` has to be placed right after the `SpreadsheetSetCellValue` for it to work on each sheet. No where else did it work. That part is solved. But the formatting is still only working on the first sheet. **edit** Updated my code to reflect what I'm using. It's shorter, but still have 115 lines. I tried using [http://trycf.com/scratch-pad](http://trycf.com/scratch-pad), but couldn't figure out how to save the scratch-pad?

Comment: Nevermind I got it to save, just noticed the instructions at the bottom of the editor. [My attempt](http://trycf.com/gist/f3235fe83fa71b321685addf3e38b41d/acf2016?theme=monokai) This actually works here, so I'll have to figure out where I'm going wrong with my environment.

Comment: @Leigh I added an edit above. I got the width to work across all the sheets. You mentioned that there's a way to shorten my code considerably, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSE5BE1B04-D4F1-4698-BCDF-54B36D67A66D.html) only operates on the active sheet. So invoking it once, at the very end, is not going to work. That function must be invoked on *each* sheet, for *each* column you wish to modify.

As you noticed, the column width can only be changed *after* you add some data to that column. The reason for this is that the columns (or cells) are not actually created until you apply a value or formula. So if you try and modify their properties, before they even exist, nothing happens. The same rules apply to "formats": the cells must exist before you can apply a format.

**Optimizations:**

A few tips that will greatly simplify the original code and improve readability:

1. Since the report will use the same query columns, on every sheet, this is a perfect job for a UDF. Instead of copying over the same code for every sheet, just create a single function that populates an arbitrary sheet name using the supplied query.

   ```
   function populateSummarySheet( any workbook
           , string sheetName
           , date reportDate
           , query qryData
           , boolean createNewSheet ) {
   ```

   Then invoke the function as many times as you need:

   ```
    Workbook = SpreadsheetNew("FirstSheet");
    populateSummarySheet(Workbook, "FirstSheet", reportDate, query1, false);
    populateSummarySheet(Workbook, "SecondSheet", reportDate, query2, true);
    populateSummarySheet(Workbook, "ThirdSheet", reportDate, query3, true);
    // ....
   ```

   **If you are unfamiliar with functions in CF, be sure to read up on how to properly scope function local variables**. A common gotcha is forgetting to scope all of your function local variables, which can often create weird and difficult to reproduce problems down the line.
2. CF9+ supports shortcuts for structure and array creation. ie

   ```
   headerFormat = { bold="true", fontsize=18, font="Calibri" };
   ```
3. If you need to format *all* cells in a particular row or column, it is more efficient to format the row or column, instead of each individual cell. See the documentation on: [SpreadSheetFormatRow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-676f.html), [SpreadSheetFormatColumn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6806.html) [SpreadSheetFormatColumns](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-677a.html)

   Also, Excel limits how many styles you can apply. Formatting individual cells uses up more styles, increasing the likelihood you will exceed the limits: [SpreadsheetFormatRow abruptly stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817997/spreadsheetformatrow-abruptly-stops-working/37820034#37820034) The limits for the newer .xlsx format are higher than for .xls format. So when possible, it is better to use .xlsx workbooks, instead of .xls.

> I have CF 2016 and the prod server is CF 9

Like I mentioned in another thread, using different versions in Dev and Prod is a *really* bad idea. As it will make it impossible to test your code. If you do a search, you can still find downloads for older versions. For example: [Direct download link for ColdFusion 9 Installer (64-bit Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615537/direct-download-link-for-coldfusion-9-installer-64-bit-windows)

Comment: Thanks, this will help a lot. Just one question though I think I already know the answer. The `function` would be inside the `<cfscript>` along with all the rest of the code that I've got right?

Comment: Yes. That said, while there is nothing technically wrong with doing that, usually you want to keep functions separate and organized into structured components. Unfortunately CF9 does not have as good support for cfscript as say CF11. So with certain things you will have to decide if you want to stick with cfml only, or have a mix of cfml and cfscript (a little less readable).

Comment: One note about functions. If you are not familiar with them, be sure to read up scoping variables and the `var` and `local` scopes. An very common gotcha is forgetting to scope *all* function local variables. Then running into weird threading problems later when the function is used within shared scopes.

Comment: @Mike - FYI - I rolled back the last edit to preserve the context of the original question. Otherwise, the existing answers no longer make sense ;-). BTW, if you are new to Stack Overflow, might take a minute to review the [Quick Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It works a little differently than a discussion forum. S.O. uses a Q&A format: one question per thread, many answers.  Also, side note "comments" are considered temporary. Extended discussions in comments can be (and frequently are) deleted by moderators without warning ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought of my question no longer making sense once I changed the script. I have gotten everything completed. After changing to xlsx format the formatting works across all sheets and the column width remains what I want it to be. In case you are interested [HERE] (http://trycf.com/gist/bc476779c0132f3c4ffb2a054fc65fd2/acf2016?theme=monokai) is the completed `script`. I really appreciate the help in simplifying and optimizing as well.

Comment: You are welcome.  Though do not forget to `var/local` scope all of the function local variables.  Lack of scoping can cause all kinds of weird problems under load. BTW, does the report really need to display multiple queries on the same sheet? If so, you could just make the query arguments optional. I could be totally off base, but was thinking you wanted each on a separate sheet like this:  http://trycf.com/gist/06aadc984fa2eb1c50686fc40dae358b/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: The first sheet is only running one query the next two sheets are running 3 queries each, that's why I have that in there. From what I was reading the `function` arguments are required not optional. Is there a way to make them optional? I didn't see it. I'll go back and re-read though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say they *are* optional by default. So you do not need extra boolean arguments. Just check the `arguments` scope to verify they exist: `structKeyExists(arguments, "argumentName")`. That said, it still seems like it could be reduced a little further :) Maybe [this previous version](http://trycf.com/gist/06aadc984fa2eb1c50686fc40dae358b/acf2016?theme=monokai) will give you some ideas.